# Firebase distribution Error: failed to upload distribution. it took longer than expected to process your binary, please try again

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

- '[' success == success ']'
- firebase appdistribution:distribute test.apk  
  --app 1:1234567890:android:0a1b2c3d4e5f67890  
  --release-notes "Bug fixes and improvements" --testers-file testers.txt
  i  getting app details...
  i  uploading distribution...
  Error: failed to upload distribution. it took longer than expected to process your binary, please try again

Build failed :|
Step 6 script `Post-build script` exited with status code 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue here.
I tried to update my firebase-tools but it didn't work, I think that is a firebase internal problem.

UPDATE
It is a internal firebase problem, as you can see:

[image]

See: https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/Uv14uNHr9xKNfPQx3r2j